# Expanding and collapsing table cell values using js/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table where I need to click the Option 1 or Option 2 etc. When they are clicked the cell that has Option n has to be populated with JSON values as shown and when again the same Option n is clicked they must be hidden

[image]

I had tried with

```js
function showHideMore(checkBoxValue)
{
if(checkBoxValue == 'A1') return {'name': 'Clark', age:'39', address:'Washington D.C.'}
if(checkBoxValue == 'B1') return {'name': 'Bob', age:'26', address:'Texas'}
if(checkBoxValue == 'C1') return {'name': 'Angelina', age:'31', address:'Ohio'}
}
```

```html
<table id="tbl" class="dupes" align="center" width="100%" border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="first"><input type="checkbox" id="select-all"></th>
            <th class="second">Edit</th>
            <th class="third">&nbsp;</th>
            <th class="fourth">Timestamp</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr>
        <td class="first"><input class="selects" type="checkbox" value="A1" id="r0"></td>
        <td class="second"><a target="_blank" href="www.uitshj.org?show=A1">1</a></td>
        <td class="third"><a target="_blank" href="www.uitshj.org?show=A1" onclick="showHideMore()">Option 1</a></td>
        <td class="fourth">2018-08-26T10:38:01.602Z</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="first"><input class="selects" type="checkbox" value="B1" id="r1"></td>
        <td class="second"><a target="_blank" href="www.uitshj.org?show=B1">2</a></td>
        <td class="third"><a target="_blank" href="www.uitshj.org?show=B1" onclick="showHideMore()">Option 2</a></td>
        <td class="fourth">2018-08-26T10:23:42.119Z</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="first"><input class="selects" type="checkbox" value="C1" id="r2"></td>
        <td class="second"><a target="_blank" href="www.uitshj.org?show=C1">3</a></td>
        <td class="third"><a target="_blank" href="www.uitshj.org?show=C" onclick="showHideMore()">Option 3</a></td>
        <td class="fourth">2018-08-26T01:05:00.171Z</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: `onclick="showHideMore()"` does not pass a parameter `checkBoxValue` which your handler `function showHideMore(checkBoxValue)` expects. This leads to `checkBoxValue` always being `undefined` in your handler. Using inline event handlers you are not going to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give each option a class and an id:

```
<td class="third"><a href="#" class='option' id='option_2'>Option 2</a></td>
```

Then hook into it with JQuery, something like this should work:

```
var myJson = {
  option_1: {'name': 'Clark', age:'39', address:'Washington D.C.'},
  option_2: {'name': 'Bob', age:'26', address:'Texas'},
  option_3: {'name': 'Angelina', age:'31', address:'Ohio'}
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.option').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    id = $(this).attr('id');
    values = myJson[id];

    parent = $(this).parent('td')
    existing_content = parent.find('.option_content')
    if( existing_content.length ){ //if content exists, remove it
      existing_content.remove()
    } else { //else add the content
      content = "<div class='option_content'>" + values.name + "<br>" + values.age + "<br>" + values.address + "</div>";
      $(this).after(content)
    }
  })
})
```

Here's a full working example:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<table id="tbl" class="dupes" align="center" width="100%" border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="first"><input type="checkbox" id="select-all"></th>
            <th class="second">Edit</th>
            <th class="third">&nbsp;</th>
            <th class="fourth">Timestamp</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr>
        <td class="first"><input class="selects" type="checkbox" value="A1" id="r0"></td>
        <td class="second"><a target="_blank" href="www.uitshj.org?show=A1">1</a></td>
        <td class="third"><a href="#" class='option' id='option_1' >Option 1</a></td>
        <td class="fourth">2018-08-26T10:38:01.602Z</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="first"><input class="selects" type="checkbox" value="B1" id="r1"></td>
        <td class="second"><a target="_blank" href="www.uitshj.org?show=B1">2</a></td>
        <td class="third"><a href="#" class='option' id='option_2' >Option 2</a></td>
        <td class="fourth">2018-08-26T10:23:42.119Z</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="first"><input class="selects" type="checkbox" value="C1" id="r2"></td>
        <td class="second"><a target="_blank" href="www.uitshj.org?show=C1">3</a></td>
        <td class="third"><a href="#" class='option' id='option_3'>Option 3</a></td>
        <td class="fourth">2018-08-26T01:05:00.171Z</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<script>

var myJson = {
  option_1: {'name': 'Clark', age:'39', address:'Washington D.C.'},
  option_2: {'name': 'Bob', age:'26', address:'Texas'},
  option_3: {'name': 'Angelina', age:'31', address:'Ohio'}
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.option').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    id = $(this).attr('id');
    values = myJson[id];

    parent = $(this).parent('td')
    existing_content = parent.find('.option_content')
    if( existing_content.length ){ //if content exists, remove it
      existing_content.remove()
    } else { //else add the content
      content = "<div class='option_content'>" + values.name + "<br>" + values.age + "<br>" + values.address + "</div>";
      $(this).after(content)
    }
  })
})
</script>
```